# Telepathy vs. Telekinesis in Marvel Universe

Tags: marvel, x-men, telepathy, telekinesis

I've been wondering why [Professor X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X#Powers_and_abilities), generally considered to be one of the most powerful mutants, was susceptible to *physical attacks* to his head and body by people using helmets to block his telepathic mind-reading abilities (Magneto and Juggernaut for example).

My point is that telekinesis, the power to move objects with thoughts (used by characters such as Jean Grey, Emma Frost, and Psylocke to name a few) is also an ability that stems out of the mind, so **are they just extensions of the same ability** in the X-Men Universe and if so, why doesn't Xavier ever expand into that area?

[image]

Comment: FYI Emma Frost does not have telekinetic abilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they aren't manifestations of the same ability.  Most super-powers are controlled mentally, and of course each superhero's non-super abilities are also all controlled via their minds as well.

- Most telepaths, such as Psylocke, Professor X, the White Queen, are not telekinetic.
- Telekinessis in its pure form is significantly more rare than telepathy, but there are some pure telekinetics such as [Hellion](http://marvel.com/universe/Hellion) who are not telepathic.
- "Impure" telekinetics, who have the ability to move objects or
  manifest energy fields by virtue of some related power, usually have
  no telepathy either.  Prominent examples include the Invisible Woman and her brother.

One reason it seems as if telepathy and telekinesis go hand-in-hand is because of the Jean Grey family heritage, with the original X-man and her four genetic descendants (Rachel Grey, Nate Grey, Cable and Stryfe) all displaying similar power.

Of note, perhaps, is that Jean initially only displayed telekinetic powers; her telepathy developed when the X-Men believed Xavier had died (circa *X-Men* 42), possibly catalyzed by Xavier. When the O5 team came forward in time, Jean again had her telepathy activated.

Comment: Psylocke hasn't been telekinetic for most of her existance, although there was a brief period during Morisson's run when her power was switched to telekinesis instead of telepathy without explanation.

Comment: I think I meant by mental only that for example if a train is coming at you, you react by stopping it with your mind and not creating a net ala Green Lantern from DC @DougM.

Comment: @DougM - There is an explanation for Psylocke's telekinetic shift.  During Morisson's run, but not in New X-Men, Psylocke had a run in with the Shadow King and imprisoned him in her mind.  Afterwards her powers shifted from telepathy to telekinesis... I still no idea why and if I recall correctly she died shortly after that and was brought back to life with her telepathic powers intact by Jamie Braddock (her brother who has reality warping abilities).

Comment: "I'm imprisoning the shadow king so now I have telepathy" is worse than no explanation.  Of course, it IS Morrison, so nonsense is par.

Comment: *"Most telepaths, such as Psylocke, Professor X, the White Queen, are not telekinetic."* That's completely inaccurate. Psylocke has significant telekentic abilities. **http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Elizabeth_Braddock_(Earth-616)#Powers_and_Abilities** . While Emma Frost has latent telekinetic abilities. **http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Emma_Frost_(Earth-616)#Powers_and_Abilities**

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy Well, she's telekinetic now, but she wasn't originally. [Jean Grey's attempt to help Betsy deal with the Shadow King somehow swapped their powers, leaving Betsy telekinetic.](https://www.marvel.com/characters/psylocke)

Answer (score 9):

### In regard to telekinesis (also called psychokinesis) and telepathy:

- All telepaths are not telekinetic (Charles Xavier), and all telekinetics are not telepaths (Vance Astrovick/Justice).
- Telekinetic effects can be achieved in a variety of ways using magical abilities or advanced scientific technologies. The [Marvel Universe has an abundance of psychokinetic characters](http://marvel.wikia.com/Telekinesis) with telekinetic abilities, at varying levels, from a variety of sources.
- In the case where a person has both, the capacities of each ability may be unequally distributed (Psylocke). In others, a person may have both capacities at outstanding levels (Cassandra Nova, Phoenix, Absolon Mercator) and can be used for a variety of amazing feats.
- Telekinesis and Telepathy are both completely distinct abilities, their only similarity is they are both mentally controlled and tend to require active manipulation of the powers, unlike passive mutant abilities such as Colossus' transformation to Osmium which once activated remains until he changes again.
- Mutant abilities come in a spectrum of relationships and some of them can be found in pairs such as the powers of telekinesis and telepathy in the Jean Grey family line.

### On the subject of Charles Xavier

- Depending on when you read the character, there have been times where he has exhibited telekinetic ability. But that has fluctuated depending on the writers and for the most part his telekinesis has been rarely demonstrated in modern comics.
- Charles Xavier is primarily telepathic. But contrary to most knowledge, Xavier's genome had quite a number of other potential genetic capacities including telekinesis. We learn this when the character [Cassandra Nova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_Nova) appears and has all of Xavier's considerable genetic potential at her fingertips.

> - Cassandra Nova began life at the same time as Charles Xavier. Conceived without a body, Cassandra improvised one by copying Xavier's DNA to make her own body, effectively becoming his twin sister.
> - Jean Grey later discovered that Cassandra Nova is the mummudrai (from a Shi'ar legend, meaning opposite) of Charles Xavier. "Legend says each of us faces our own personal mummudrai in the womb, shortly before birth - it is our first experience of the alien, the other, the different." In reality, the mummudrai are a parasitic species born bodiless on the astral plane, and it was only through becoming entangled with Charles Xavier's developing telepathic mind that Cassandra Nova created a body for herself.
> - The mummudrai are usually forced to fight with the mind of their host over a body. However, given the vast potential in Xavier's genome, Cassandra Nova was able to build her own body, mimicking human traits as best she can. **Cassandra Nova is able to access the full spectrum of latent mutant functions in Xavier's genome (she seemingly has the powers of Charles Xavier, the ones he could have and the ones he might receive as a result of latent mutation), granting herself vast psionic powers. These powers include telepathy, telekinesis, and a phasing ability.**

Answer (score 0):

Eric Stealth (aka Vegeance, Arch Sabre, Cosmic Phoenix) is a superhero in all Comic Universes that no one mentions or heard of. His telekinetic powers manifested at age 3 when his then nanny saw him manipulating the fire lit by a match light up a candle. At age 5, he accidentally turned boiling water in vapour that was to be used on his mother's tea. Due to his innate abilities at such a young age manipulating fire and water and being a danger to his older siblings, he was sent to an orphanage (much like Cyclops). At age 6 he developed a mistrust of people and caretakers around him that inadvertently activated his telepathic abilities creating fantasy worlds (or alternate universes) that portrays a loving family and acceptance of friends.

Charles Xavier was accidentally telepathically called upon when Eric was creating one of his alternate universes. Charles having experienced such power from a boy at age 6 tried to reach out to him but was blocked out from entering Eric's mind completely due to Eric's inability to relate and trust people after he was sent to the orphanage.

Like most mutants he became an outcast never relating to his peers in grammar and an high school. His teachers were often full of admiration in that he excelled in the arts and later on in technology. After graduating from high school his telepathic and telekinetic powers became very useful after accepting several jobs in medicine and the computer industry. He used this to his potential at early adulthood becoming one of the most powerful technopaths in world (much like Apocalypse). With his experience in health and medicine his mutation allowed him to repair his body quickly from massive injuries (much like Wolverine) and heal others (i.e., Elixir).

Above and beyond his powers emanate throughout the universe and was called upon and chose to become a host for the Phoenix Force. Much like Jean Grey / Dark Phoenix he was set out to destroy unimportant and war infested galaxies, but chose very hard not to eliminate them due to his peaceful nature.

This is when he got in conflict with Galactus. With his powerful never-ending telekinetic and telepathic powers he decimated and turned Galactus into dust particles with a blink of his eye and made his entire entity remain as dust in order not to destroy any more worlds and/or galaxies.

During the Age of Apocalypse, he created an alternate universe to lock Apocalyse into vacuum forever and telepathically altered his mindset to think that he was still destroying the earth and humans and making evil mutants flourish.

So yes telekinesis and telepathy are separate entities of power. But having both in conjunction with each other much like Eric Stealth has is an advantage and very dangerous in any comic universes. Eric still has not fully mastered his control of his alterego maniacal pure instinctual prowess of being a Dark / Cosmic Phoenix.

This is where he eventually led Charles into his his mind to figure out how to control it and prevent it from fully consuming him.

Answer (score 0):

Not only are telekinesis and telepathy separate psionic abilities in the Marvel universe, which don't always correlate, but it is also the case that telepathy has many different subcategories, and not everyone has access to all kinds.  For example, mind control, reading thoughts, reading memories, the ability to project your thoughts to others, psychic attacks, psychic shields, memory erasure, clairvoyance, and precognition are kinds of psychic abilities in the Marvel Universe; and their are various characters like Mesmero (mind control), Apocalypse (psychic shields and psychic traps) and Psylocke (psychic attacks) who only have access to one or a few of these abilities, not always all of them.